# Simple forvalues loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, web, screen-scraping

is there a simple way in Python to loop over a simple list of numbers?
I want to scrape some data from different URLs that only differ in 3 numbers?

I'm quite new to python and couldn't figure out an easy way to do it.
Thanks a lot!
Here's my code:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://www.example.com/3322")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = bsObj.findAll("table",{"class":"MainContent"})[0]
rows=table.findAll("td")

csvFile = open("/Users/Max/Desktop/file1.csv", 'wt')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
try:
    for row in rows:
        csvRow=[]
        for cell in row.findAll(['tr', 'td']):
            csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
            writer.writerow(csvRow)
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

In Stata this would be like:

```
 foreach i of 13 34 55 67{
     html = urlopen("http://www.example.com/`i'")
      ....
      }
```

Thanks a lot!
Max

Comment: Try in range, something like for x in range(0, 9): print(x)

Answer (score 2):

I've broken your original code into functions simply to make clearer what I think is the answer to your question: use a simple loop, and `.format()` to construct urls and filenames.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_url(url):
    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = bsObj.findAll("table",{"class":"MainContent"})[0]
    rows=table.findAll("td")
    return rows

def write_csv_data(path, rows):
    csvFile = open(path, 'wt')
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    try:
        for row in rows:
            csvRow=[]
            for cell in row.findAll(['tr', 'td']):
                csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
                writer.writerow(csvRow)
    finally:
        csvFile.close()

for i in (13, 34, 55, 67):
    url = "http://www.example.com:3322/{}".format(i)
    csv_path = "/Users/MaximilianMandl/Desktop/file-{}.csv".format(i)

    rows = scrape_url(url)
    write_csv_data(csv_path, rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

i would use set.intersection() for that:

```
mylist=[1,16,8,32,7,5]
fieldmatch=[5,7,16]

intersection = list(set(mylist).intersection(fieldmatch))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with stata, but. It looks like the python equivalent might be simply:

```
import request 
for i in [13 34 55 67]:
         response =  request("http://www.example.com/{}".format(i))
          ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this it to apply the filter inside the loop:

```
mylist=[1,16,8,32,7,5]
for myitem in mylist:
    if myitem in (5,7,16):
        print myitem # or print(myitem)
```

This may not, however, be the most elegant way to do it. If you wanted to store a new list of the matching results, you can use a list comprehension:

```
mylist=[1,16,8,32,7,5]
fieldmatch=[5,7,16]
filteredlist=[ x for x in mylist if x in fieldmatch ]
```

You can then take `filteredlist` which contains only the items in `mylist` that match `fieldmatch` (in other words your original list filtered by your criteria) and iterate over it like any other list:

```
for myitem in filteredlist:
    # Perform whatever process you want to each item here
    do_something_with(myitem)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thx. But I can't see how I loop through the whole code for each number. Sry for this 'simple' question.